# Issue in get Total value and field name null in join SQLITE android

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, left-join, multiple-tables

Hello friends i have 6 tables

```
property_master -->p_id, p_name, p_address,p_city,P_state,p_country,p_is_active

tanant_master-->t_id,p_id,t_name,

property_unit--> unit_id,p_id,unit_name 

unit_info-->unit_info_id,unit_id,p_id,p_rent, p_isrent

property_assign-->t_assign_id,unit_info_id,p_id,t_id 

transction_master-->t_master_id,p_id,unit_info_id ,t_id ,user_cat_id,amount,date
```

**My requirement is** 
i need all list of property and unit information which i have suppose i have 3 property and in first property A include 2 unit like A1,A2 than i need list like A,A1,A2 and all information about that so i make query for that

**Query**

```
SELECT property_master.p_id AS "PID",
property_master.p_name AS "PropertyName",
property_master.p_address AS "ProepertyAddress",
property_master.p_city AS "ProepertyCity",
property_master.p_state AS "ProepertyState",
property_master.p_country AS "ProepertyCountry",
tanant_master.t_name AS "TanantName",
property_unit.unit_name as "unit_name",
(SELECT SUM(amount)
FROM transction_master
WHERE unit_info_id = unit_info.unit_info_id and transction_master.date
between '2015-01-01' and '2015-12-31'
) AS "TotalIncome",
(SELECT SUM(amount)
FROM transction_master
WHERE unit_info_id = unit_info.unit_info_id and transction_master.date
between '2015-01-01' and '2015-12-31'
) AS "TotalExpense"
FROM property_master left join transction_master on   property_master.p_id  = transction_master.p_id left join property_assign on
(property_master.p_id=property_assign.p_id)
left join tanant_master on
(tanant_master.t_id=property_assign.t_id)
left join unit_info on   
(unit_info.unit_info_id=transction_master.unit_info_id) 
left join property_unit on property_unit.unit_id = unit_info.unit_id
where property_master.p_is_active=0    and property_master.r_id=75
GROUP BY property_master.p_id ,tanant_master.t_id
```

When i run above query it give list of only main property which i have not unit name and also TOtalIncome ,TotalExpense, getting null , but i have  so any idea how can i solve it?

Comment: As per your issue description you are getting an null pointer exception if that is the case, can you please post your log cat trace.

Comment: Kesh1234 : query not show any error message  but i get value in unitname , totalincome ,totalexpense value column as a blank .

Comment: Are you sure you have data in database?

Comment: Kesh1234  : Yes i have value in database

Comment: I think "between '2015-01-01' and '2015-12-31'" may not work in SQLLIT

Comment: Koushik  : i don't think issue in date format because i make lots of query with that format it is working also ,in this my above case  i think issue in join